# New moon sighting follow local or Saudi or international sighting?

Tags: practical-islam, fiqh, ramadan, islamic-scholar, lunar-calendar

What are the evidences for each view and it is not as easy as just following the new moon in your country I believe because there are many issues which even experienced scholars find it hard to understand.

Comment: I think this answers your questuon or at least is relevant https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/35556/13438